# flutter: Unable to start the daemon process

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, daemon

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am tried to solve this issue in `VSCode`, `flutter`. I tried all possible solutions, and it works for few days then again same thing happens.

here is what i tried:

**1-**
changed in `gradle.properties` the following line

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
```

to

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m
```

and

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx512m
```

**2-**
changed in `gradle-wrapper.properties` the following line

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip
```

to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip
```

**3-**
delete the emulator and make the new one

**4-**
free some space

I have windows 10 in my pc and, 64-bit operating system. please let me know if anyone can resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The general steps I would use are:

- run flutter doctor in terminal
- if you are using an emulator make sure it has enough space (often it needs a restart to clear junk files created upon consecutive deploys)
- if the gradle files have been modified it is recommended to open them with Android Studio (Android folder of the application). If anything is missing the IDE will prompt you to install the missing dependencies.